# elasticsearch balance performance calculation

Tags: elasticsearch

i am using elastic search (i can't change it) and i have have a situation like this:

I have a list of transaction es.

in the last 5 days

- T1 = +10
- T2 = +20
- T3 = -30

Then i have a global balance 100

I would like something like that:

(always) in the last 5 days

- doc1 balance = 100 (+10)
- doc2 balance = 110 (+20)
- doc3 balance = 130 (-30)
- doc4 balance = 100 (actual balance - i can have not this last row because is simple to add to the list)

Honestly i have not "global balance" together to transactions to start calculation right now because i keep it in another index but i could use a join field to take document keeping balance in the same index and use it as parents. (i can do it)

Actually i am achieving the result getting data from server and executing calculation in frontEnd.

So i wondering if there is a way to get a list of data closest possibile to my result.

PS. I am using ES 7 so i am not able to use for example "runtime_mappings"

Thanks